# PayPal rest api, PHP SDK, billing, I get error REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am getting an error REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING 
when executing PayPal's sample/billing/CreatePlan.php with
my own clientId and secret.  It works fine using
the provided clientId and secret.

REPRODUCE BY:

Download PayPal-PHP-SDK v0.14.2

go to  sample/billing

run
php CreatePlan.php

Line 9 on this file includes the 
bootstrap.php program. This is 
where the clientId and secret are defined.

If I use the existing clientId and secret
it will work fine.  If I substitute in my
own clientId and secret it will give the
error message shown here.

```
[myprompt]$ php CreatePlan.php
Warning: This sample may require a server to handle return URL. Cannot execute in  command line. Defaulting URL to http://localhost/sample/billing

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(1) CREATED PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------
    REQUEST:
{"name":"T-Shirt of the Month Club Plan","description":"Template       creation.","type":"fixed",
"payment_definitions":[{"name":"Regular Payments","type":"REGULAR","frequency":"Month",
"frequency_interval":"2","cycles":"12","amount":{"value":"100.00","currency":"USD"},
"charge_models":[{"type":"SHIPPING","amount":{"value":"10.00","currency":"USD"}}]}],
"merchant_preferences":{"return_url":"http://localhost/sample/billing /ExecuteAgreement.php?success=true",
"cancel_url":"http://localhost/sample/billing/ExecuteAgreement.php?success=false","auto_bill_amount":"yes","initial_fail_amount_action":    "CONTINUE","max_fail_attempts":"0","setup_fee":{"value":"1.00","currency":"USD"}}}

    RESPONSE:
ERROR:Got Http response code 403 when 
accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/.    {"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING",
"message":"Access token does not have required scope",
"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api  /#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","debug_id":"261257fb27891"}
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

My own clientId and secret work fine with all
the payment samples.

Comment: Btw, just so you know, if you are using PHP5.4 or higher, you can now get samples working on web by using PHP built in server by just running one command: 

    php -f samples/index.php

Just make sure you are using the latest code. Release would be made soon for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of this error you need to make sure that the REST Application that you have created on the developer.paypal.com have the check mark for **"Subcription"** under the **"APP CAPABILITIES"  -->>  "Advanced options"**

You can refer the screen shot below :

[image]